# Writing commands to cmd with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, usb, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox to attach a usb device. This usb device only works under 32 bit. My host os is Windows 7 64 bit, my Guest Windows 7 32 bit.

I found code to write to the command prompt and read it back out, this has been tested and works very well. But now after I have read and want to write again the command prompt just freezes. I have no idea why it does that... I also tried the command without VB and the driver attach fine.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Results As String
    Private test As Double
    Private test2 As String

    'The "Delegate" is used to correct the threading issue (Can't update control directly in VB.net 08/10), and invokes the needed text
update.
    Private Delegate Sub delUpdate()
    Private Finished As New delUpdate(AddressOf UpdateText)

    Private Sub UpdateText()
        resultsTextBox.Text = Results
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim CMDThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf CMDAutomate)
        CMDThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CMDAutomate()

        Dim myprocess As New Process
        Dim StartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

        'Starts the CMD Prompt
        StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True

        'Required to redirect
        StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False

        'Disables the creation of a CMD Prompt outside application.
        StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False


        myprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo
        myprocess.Start()
        Dim SR As System.IO.StreamReader = myprocess.StandardOutput
        Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter = myprocess.StandardInput

        'Runs the command you entered...
        'SW.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
        SW.WriteLine("cd C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox")
        SW.WriteLine("vboxmanage list usbhost")
        'Exits CMD Prompt 
        'SW.WriteLine("exit")

        'Displayes the results...
        Results = SR.ReadToEnd
        'Im reading the string out to get the right Device id
        test = InStr(Results, "0x0547", CompareMethod.Text)
        test = test - 58
        test2 = Mid(Results, test, 36)
        'test2 gives 80be0bc1-6f69-4886-868f-c8857bff34c1
        'this is the right id, if i try to input it myselves with:
        'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage controlvm "test" usbattach
        '80be0bc1-6f69-4886-868f-c8857bff34c1
        'it works...

        SW.WriteLine("vboxmanage controlvm " + Chr(34) + "test" + Chr(34) + "usbattach " + test2)
        SW.WriteLine("exit")
        Results = SR.ReadToEnd
        SW.Close()
        SR.Close()

        'Invokes Finished delegate, which updates textbox with the results text
        Invoke(Finished)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ReadToEnd doesn't finish because the Command Window is still open. I would run half of your commands and then read it in after the EXIT command is called. Then you would simply need to parse the result string and run another Command Window process.

Comment: I made a second thread and it seems to work now, thx for the help!